# Why doesn't my program work in another computer?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with my program because it works well in my computer but it doesn't work in others when I use my .exe. The problem is that I need to use a picture and when I load it in my computer I can load .bmp, .jpg, .gif and .png. However, when I throw my program in other computer it is only able to read .bmp.
This is my code:

```
picture= new QImage(fichier); //fichier=QString
```

Comment: Since you don't provide a lot of information, I'm taking a wild guess: 64bit vs. 32bit?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. Different processor, different architecture, any other from a long list of possible reasons. You should recompile your program on the computer where you want to use it.

Comment: fichier is French, could you please translate it to make the question more clear!? Also could you please tell us if you are loading an actual file on disk or an embedded resource!?

Comment: Are you building with static libraries (.lib) or dynamic libraries (.dll, .so)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you've built Qt it may or may not have the image support using plugins, or system library. If you go [here to the Qt docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-windows-deployment.html#plugins) it gives you more information on deploying Qt and what you need to include.